# AnyDAC (FireDAC) - Open transaction after TBlobField.GetAsString

Tags: delphi, transactions, firedac, autocommit, anydac

at the moment we are migrating the database component of our **Delphi7** application from the **BDE** components to the **AnyDAC (FireDAC) Version 8.0.5** components.

The following prerequisites are given:

- On our form we have one TADConnection, one TADQuery and one TADTable. The TADQuery is the MasterSource for the TADTable. No special changes have been made to the settings of the AnyDAC components, so the **AutoCommit** mode is active.
- Furhtermore we have one TDBMemo on our form which is linked to an ftMemo field of the TADTable (Firebird FieldType = Blob / Size = 240 / Subtype = Text)

During the loading of the blob text field content (TBlobField.GetAsString) the TADTable starts automatically an transaction *which would not committed*.

Is this behavior normal? Do we have any possiblity to avoid this open transaction?
Please note, deactivating of the AutoCommit is no option at the moment.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Yes, that is normal. So long you're not fetching BLOB data along with the detail tuple, AnyDAC (FireDAC) starts an implicit transaction. Think about it like every read or write from or to DBMS issues transaction.

Comment: @Victoria:  It would be good if someone who knows what they are talking about (e.g. you) could edit the `anydac`tag to mention that it is now FireDAC, since whatever version of Delphi introduced it..

Comment: @MartynA, it's already there _"In 2013 AnyDAC was sold to Embarcadero, renamed FireDAC and limited to only support Delphi platform."_

Comment: @Victoria:  Oh, I missed that - I was only looking at the hover-over hint for the tag.  Thanks.

Comment: @Victoria: thank you for your hint! That was exactly the reason for the automatically startet transaction! May I can ask you another question... Is there any possibilty to check what is part of an transaction? I mean can I check the prepared sql commands between starttransaction and commit / rollback?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand. You can access `ADTable.Command.SQLText` to get the current command, if that is what you're asking for.

Comment: No Problem, maybe my question was not clear enough...
1. The TADConnection starts the transaction automatically
2. An TADTable or an TADQuery or both executes some sql commands
3. The TADConnection made an commit of the startet transaction
4. Now the changes of the TADTable / TADQuery are posted to the database

Do I have any chance to check which changes of the TADTable / TADQuery would be committed in step 3?

Comment: Yes. If you for example assign an explicit transaction object and read the `Text` property from inside its `OnBeforeCommit` event handler.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is a normal behavior. So long you are not fetching BLOB data along with the detail tuple, AnyDAC starts an implicit transaction for fetching those BLOB data.